# sendmail on Red Hat won't work for different directory

Tags: sendmail, redhat

I have scripts that generate files and mail them to the appropriate people on a Red Hat linux box. The scripts work fine from several directories. However, from one directory (the one that it should run from) it appears to run but the mail is never delivered. Anyone ever have this problem before?

Comment: Can you share more details please?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible script, the directory paths and permissions.

Comment: This actually turned out to be a problem with uuencode. Thought I had used identical code but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a uuencode error. I thought I had used the exact same file in both directories but apparently not.